# javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB (WAS 8.5)

Tags: java

I'm migration my application from WAS 7.0 to WAS 8.5. One of the job doing JNDI lookup to get the MQConnectionFactory and Queue. The same code moved from WAS 7 to 8.5 is giving the below error.

***Note:***
**I have already updated the naming.jar, namingclient.jar and MQ related jars.**

Please help me to resolve it.

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:400) ~[namingclient.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:463) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at com.cigna.dms.outbound.outbound.service.DMSMessageProducer.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[ReportingOutbound.jar:na]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor439.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) ~[na:2.6 (12-16-2014)]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:391) ~[namingclient.jar:WAS85.SERV1 [gm1216.02]]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: Unable to init plugins
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:233) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugins(PluginRegistry.java:214) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugins(PluginRegistry.java:220) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.initializePlugins(ORB.java:636) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.orbParameters(ORB.java:1386) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1293) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1694) ~[na:na]
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:377) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:83) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:59) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:102) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        ... 17 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Invalid Implementation Key, com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.WLMPlugin
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ImplFactory.loadClassFromKey(ImplFactory.java:369) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ImplFactory.loadClassFromKey(ImplFactory.java:360) ~[com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.wlm.Factory$2.run(Factory.java:98) ~[com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar:na]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:341) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at com.ibm.ws.wlm.Factory.loadClass(Factory.java:96) ~[com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.wlm.client.WLMClient.init(WLMClient.java:130) ~[com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:228) ~[na:na]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Check that you have `com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.WLMPlugin` in the CLASSPATH

Comment: Karthik, thanks for quick reply.The com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.WLMPlugin is part of the AppServer (ibmorb.jar), I have included the AppServer library path for the job. But still same issue. 

\n\n\n

WASLIBDir=/opt/was85_1/AppServer/lib/*